# how i get all data from firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database with this schema:

[image]

I tested this code but I can't get any msg from the database.  I would appreciate your help.

```
 private void Add_Chat(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        root.child("ChatSpace").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String nom=dataSnapshot.child("ChatSpace").child("msg").getValue(String.class);
                System.out.println(nom);  //prints "Do you have data? You'll love Firebase."
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to get messages from all keys ?

Comment: read the documentation of firebase, everything is explained there!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `ChatSpace` is a direct chlid of your Firebase database root, to get all messages please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference chatSpaceRef = rootRef.child("ChatSpace");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String msg = ds.child("msg").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", msg);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
chatSpaceRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
bbbName
bbbName
Name
```